# Getting the index of child element of an event target

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, indexof

When I click on the image in "photo-container" class I get the element.

How can I get index of that element?

```
photoGallery(event) {
  console.log(event.target);
  this.setState({ imgSrc: event.target.src });
}

<div className="photo-container" onClick={e=> this.photoGallery(e)} >
  <img src="https://img1.jpg" alt="img-1" />
  <img src="https://img2.jpg" alt="img-2" />
  <img src="https://img3.jpg" alt="img-3" />
</div>
```

Comment: When you say `index` what exactly are you expecting to get when user clicks on say `img-2` ?

Comment: Use the data-* attribute to embed custom data, e.g.: `<img src="https://img1.jpg" alt="img-1" data-index="0" />`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution

**Solution A**

Clicking the container and getting the value which is not feasible if you have different images names you won't be able to find the index.But since in the above example which you have given has img-1,img-2 etc there is a chance to find out the index.

```js
photoGallery(event, index) {
  console.log(event.target.alt.replace('img-',''));
  this.setState({ imgSrc: event.target.src });
} 

<div className="photo-container" onClick={e=> this.photoGallery(e)}>
    <img src="https://img1.jpg" alt="img-1" />
    <img src="https://img2.jpg" alt="img-2" />
    <img src="https://img3.jpg" alt="img-3" />
</div>
```

I would recommend **Solution B**.

Instead of adding the click event on container bind the click event on the image itself for getting the proper index and other details whenever required.

```js
photoGallery(event, index) {
  console.log(event.target);
  this.setState({ imgSrc: event.target.src });
}

<div className="photo-container">
  <img src="https://img1.jpg" alt="img-1" onClick={this.photoGallery.bind(this, 0)} />
  <img src="https://img2.jpg" alt="img-2" onClick={this.photoGallery.bind(this, 1)} />
  <img src="https://img3.jpg" alt="img-3" onClick={this.photoGallery.bind(this, 2)} />
</div>
```

Comment: @Andy - It won’t run here. You need to have reactJs setup in order to make it run.

Answer (score 1):

I case you want to keep the event listener on the parent, you could stripe the index from the alt attribute of the image.

```
 var alt = event.target.alt,
   index = alt.replace('img-', '');
```

In alternative you could use the suggestion of @Igor Alemasow and use the `data-index` HTML5 attribute to get the index in js.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to bind the click event to each img and pass in an index:

```
photoGallery(index, event) {
  console.log(event.target);
  this.setState({ imgSrc: event.target.src });
}

<div className="photo-container">
  <img src="https://img1.jpg" alt="img-1" onClick={this.photoGallery.bind(this, 0)} />
  <img src="https://img2.jpg" alt="img-2" onClick={this.photoGallery.bind(this, 1)} />
  <img src="https://img3.jpg" alt="img-3" onClick={this.photoGallery.bind(this, 2)} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not attach the onClick handler to the img element instead of it's parent?

```
photoGallery(event) {
  console.log(event.target);
  this.setState({ imgSrc: event.target.src });
}

<div className="photo-container">
  <img src="https://img1.jpg" alt="img-1" onClick={e=> this.photoGallery(e)} />
  <img src="https://img2.jpg" alt="img-2" onClick={e=> this.photoGallery(e)} />
  <img src="https://img3.jpg" alt="img-3" onClick={e=> this.photoGallery(e)} />
</div>
```

Comment: This still doesn't help with finding the index. How would they find it with this code?

Comment: I assume the index would be obsolete if they bind the click handler to the element they want. It is only an assumption though as it is not clear what OP is trying to do with the index value

Answer (score 0):

Create `Image` component and add onClick event handler on image:

```
const Image = ({path, alt, index, onClick}) =>
    <img
        src={path}
        alt={alt}
        onClick={e => onClick(e, index)}
    />;
```

and use it in your render function:

```
const imagesList = [
    {
        path: 'https://img1.jpg',
        alt: 'img-1'
    },
    {
        path: 'https://img2.jpg',
        alt: 'img-2'
    },
    {
        path: 'https://img3.jpg',
        alt: 'img-3'
    }
];

const images = imagesList.map((image, i) => {
    return <Image
        {...image}
        onClick={this.photoGallery}
        key={i}
    />
});

return <div className="photo-container">
    {images}
</div>;
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might consider is keeping your image information as an array of image objects. You can add an index value and access it when you build the images in your component. Here's a simplified example using your code:

```js
class PhotoGallery extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { imgSrc: '' };
    this.photoGallery = this.photoGallery.bind(this);
  }

  photoGallery(event) {
    console.log(event.target.dataset.index);
    this.setState({ imgSrc: event.target.src });
  }

  buildImages(images) {
    return images.map(({ index, src, alt}) => {
      return <img key={index} data-index={index} src={src} alt={alt} />;
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { images } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="photo-container" onClick={this.photoGallery}>
      {this.buildImages(images)}
      </div>
    )
  }

}

const images = [
  { src: 'https://img1.jpg', alt: 'img-1', index: 1 },
  { src: 'https://img2.jpg', alt: 'img-2', index: 2 },
  // { src: 'https://img3.jpg', alt: 'img-3', index: 3 },
  // { src: 'https://img4.jpg', alt: 'img-4', index: 4 },
  { src: 'https://img5.jpg', alt: 'img-5', index: 5 }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <PhotoGallery images={images} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
img {
  margin: 1em 1em 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```